# why the select options disappears and how i can i fix it

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, select

http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/uBEDA/

```
$('#produceMenu').mouseover(function(){
       $('#produceMenu').show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $('#produceMenu').hide();
    });

$('#menuProduce').mouseover(function() {
        var pos = $('#productionMenu').position();
        $('#produceMenu').css({
            "top" : pos.top + "px",
            "left": (pos.left + 111) + "px"
        });
        $('#produceMenu').show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('#produceMenu').hide();
    });
```

why the select options disappears and how i can i fix it. in firefox it works...but in chrome it disappears.
in ie the hole sample dont work...dont know why, is there any problem with mouseover in ie?

thank you very much!

Comment: I fix the ie mouseover problem when i use jquery 1.8.3 instead of 1.10.1. but whats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

instead of mouseover , mouseout use mouseenter and mouseleave

```
    $('#produceMenu').mouseenter(function(){
           $('#produceMenu').show();
        }).mouseleave(function(){
           $('#produceMenu').hide();
    });

    $('#menuProduce').mouseenter(function() {
            var pos = $('#productionMenu').position();
            $('#produceMenu').css({
                "top" : pos.top + "px",
                "left": (pos.left + 111) + "px"
            });
            $('#produceMenu').show();
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $('#produceMenu').hide();
        });
```

check edited [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBEDA/19/)

Comment: thanks but it dont solve the problem in ie 10. maybe it failure is the absolute positioning? But then i dont understand why its working in lower jquery versions

Comment: but it solved the select problem in chrome, thanks ;-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/uBEDA/23/ i found another solution, but i didnt wor perfect, the select didnt disappear, but the menu dont react on the mouseout.